# No rule to make target for last item in list of targets

Tags: makefile

I'm experimenting with the following Makefile to better understand how they work. But I keep on getting the following error. After running `make clean` and then `make build` the following error occurs.

```
src/main.cpp src/src1.cpp src/src2.cpp src/src3.cpp
obj/main.o obj/src1.o obj/src2.o obj/src3.o
bin/AoS
Building object obj/main.o
touch obj/main.o
Building object obj/src1.o
touch obj/src1.o
Building object obj/src2.o
touch obj/src2.o
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/src3.o', needed by `build'.  Stop.
```

Here is my the contents of my Makefile.

```
#CURR_DIR = $(notdir $(shell pwd))
SRC_DIR := src/
OBJ_DIR := obj/
BIN_DIR := bin/
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)*.cpp)
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)%.o)
BIN := bin/AoS

$(info $(SRC))
$(info $(OBJ))
$(info $(BIN))

build:  $(OBJ) 
    @echo "Building the project"
    @echo "g++ -o $(BIN) $^"

$(OBJ)%.o:  
    @echo "Building object $@"
    touch $@

dirs:
    mkdir -p ./$(OBJ_DIR)
    mkdir -p ./$(SRC_DIR)
    mkdir -p ./$(BIN_DIR)

tsfls:
    touch $(SRC_DIR)src1.cpp
    touch $(SRC_DIR)src2.cpp
    touch $(SRC_DIR)src3.cpp
    touch $(SRC_DIR)src1.h
    touch $(SRC_DIR)src2.h
    touch $(SRC_DIR)src3.h
    touch $(OBJ_DIR)main.o

print:
    make build --just-print

clean:
    /bin/rm -f $(OBJ)
    /bin/rm -f $(BIN)
```

Why does it error out on the last item in `$(OBJ)`? I've reduce the the number of source files and and I still get the same error for the last item.

Thanks for the help! Here corrected version of my Makefile which borrows components from James's example.

```
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj
BIN_DIR = bin
# DIRS = $(SRC_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
# SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp) Don't rely on this method. 
SRCS = main.cpp src1.cpp src2.cpp src3.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
BIN = $(BIN_DIR)/AoS

$(info $(SRCS))
$(info $(OBJS))
$(info $(BIN))

# target: link the objects. 
#   prerequisite: make sure that the objects are compiled first.
#   prerequisite: check for any $(BIN) prerequisites.
build: $(OBJS) $(BIN)
    @echo "Building the project"
    @echo "g++ -o $(BIN) $^ A_BUNCH_OF_FLAGS"

# target: do work for creating the binary file. 
#   prerequisite: Make sure that there is a bin directory. 
$(BIN): $(BIN_DIR)

# target: If a dependency asks for files in the OBJ_DIR that have teh .o extension then
#   build those objects.
#   prerequisite: Find the matching source file in the SRC_DIR.
#   prerequisite: Find the matching header file in the SRC_DIR.
#   prerequisite: Make sure that the object directory exists.
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/%.h $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo "Building object $@"
    @echo "g++ $@ -c $<"
    touch $@

# target: Make make an executables directory if necessary. 
$(BIN_DIR): 
    @echo "Did not find an binary directory... creating one"
    mkdir -p ./$(BIN_DIR)

# target: Make an object directory if necessary. 
$(OBJ_DIR):
    @echo "Did not find an object directory... creating one"
    mkdir -p ./$(OBJ_DIR)

# Create bogus files to experiment with dependencies.
tsfls:
    touch $(SRC_DIR)/src1.cpp
    touch $(SRC_DIR)/src2.cpp
    touch $(SRC_DIR)/src3.cpp
    touch $(SRC_DIR)/src1.h
    touch $(SRC_DIR)/src2.h
    touch $(SRC_DIR)/src3.h

print:
    make build --just-print

clean:
    /bin/rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    /bin/rm -rf $(BIN_DIR)

db:
    make build --print-data-base
```

Comment: The rule to build objects is wrong.  You used `$(OBJ)` where you meant `$(OBJ_DIR)`.  Hence that rule expands to `obj/src1.o obj/src2.o obj/src3.o%.o:`.  This defines explicit rules for the first two targets and an implicit rule for the third, which doesn't match `obj/src3.o`, so no rule knows how to build that and you get the error.  If you were using a newer version of GNU make, this would actually be marked as a syntax error in your makefile.  Also, this rule is wrong because it doesn't show any prerequisites.  See James' answer for details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out MadScientist. Got that fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you got your dependencies wrong. Also, you were using :=
instead of plain =, so you were making SRC_DIR et al conditional variables.
These are tricky to get right, and I don't recommend using them unless you
actually need to do so.

Here's something which I hope will help you. It works with both gmake and Solaris Studio's dmake

```
#BEGIN
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj
BIN_DIR = bin

DIRS = $(SRC_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
SRCS = src1.cpp src2.cpp src3.cpp main.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
HDRS = $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.h)

BIN = $(BIN_DIR)/AoS

# gmake will "helpfully" assume that these are 'intermediate' files
# without .PRECIOUS, and automagically clean them up for you.
.PRECIOUS: $(HDRS) $(SRCS)

$(BIN): $(DIRS) $(OBJS)

build:  $(DIRS) $(BIN)
    @echo "Building the project"
    @echo "g++ -o $(BIN) $(OBJ)"
    touch $?

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(OBJS_DIR) $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    @echo "Building object $@"
    touch $@

$(SRC_DIR)/%:  $(SRC_DIR)
    touch $@

$(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
#END
```

Style-wise, your example appended the directory path separator (/) to each variable - that isn't something that I recommend, and it makes one's pattern
matching in rules rather ugly.

Comment: You mean _recursive variables_, not conditional variables.  Also the only reason you need the `.PRECIOUS` is you're creating your source files via implicit rules.  This is not done outside of examples like this, so this isn't something you would normally do.  Also it's not a good idea to list a directory as a prerequisite as you do with `$(SRC_DIR)` here.

Comment: I'm more used to Solaris Studio's terminology, which is where they are called conditional variables. I agree about .PRECIOUS - it's rather precious that it's necessary for this clearly contrived example.

As to whether directory existence is a good idea or not, we commonly use it in the Solaris codebase (AT&T Targetdirs, come on down!) so I suggest that it has its uses.

Comment: Thanks for your example James, it definitely helps clear up confusion.

Comment: Listing a directory as a prerequisite means that the target is considered out-of-date whenever any files are added, removed, or renamed in that directory.  This is definitely handy in certain very specific situations, but it's highly unlikely to be what you want 97% of the time, and using it simply to ensure that the directory is created (as in this answer) will lead to makefiles that behave in bizarre and inscrutable ways.  I definitely wouldn't use it in examples except for those situations where it's really needed.